# Proof that a set is dense and a map is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, operator-theory

A map $U(\theta)$ is said to be analytic at $\theta_0$ if there exist bounded operators $U_n$ such that we have 
$$U(\theta)=\sum(\theta-\theta_0)^nU_n$$
Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial in $R^n$. Consider the set $A$ of function of the  type  $$\psi(x)=p(x)e^{-\alpha x^2}$$
where $\alpha >0$

This set is dense in $L^2(R^n)$

Let $U(\theta)$ be such that
$$U(\theta)\psi(x)=e^{\frac{n \theta}{2}}p(xe^{\theta})e^{-\alpha e^{2 \theta}x^2}$$
where $\theta$ is a complex number.

How to proof that $U(\theta)$ is analytic and that real of  $U(\theta)\psi(x)$ is dense in $A$?

Comment: my mistake . I will edit the question

Comment: Your question has a lot of problems, make it precise what you want to show in the last line and what is the point of $\theta$. For a fixed $a>0$ the set $A_a=\{ p(x)e^{-a|x|^2}, p \in \Bbb{C}[x],x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\}$
is dense in $L^2(\Bbb{R}^n)$ because it contains a sequence converging to $e^{2i\pi \langle x,\xi \rangle}e^{-a|x|^2}$ and the linear combinations of complex exponentials are dense in $L^2(\Bbb{R^n/tZ^n})$ and $\bigcup_t e^{-a|x|^2}L^2(\Bbb{R^n/tZ^n})$ is dense in $L^2(\Bbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: In your first equation $U(\theta )$ is a sum over $n$ but in the third equation it appears to be a function of $n$.

Comment: $n$ is just dimension of space ($R^n$)